# Reset UL after append fot the scrollbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscrollpane

I have an `<ul>` with `overflow:auto;`, and now I want to add `<li>`s dynamically with `append();`. Unfortunately I'm not able to get the scrollbox automatically to the bottom after appending the new `<li>`:

HTML:

```
<div class="chatBoxContent" id="chatBoxContent">
    <ul id="chatMessages">...
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#chatBoxContent').jScrollPane();
    });

    $('#chatText').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!$('#chatText').val()){ 
            alert('You need to write a message!'); 
        }else{ 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/ajax.AddChat.php",
                data: {},
                success: function(html){
                    $('#chatMessages').append(html);  
                    $('#chatBoxContent').data('jsp').scrollToBottom();     
                }  
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery with jscrollpane.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky and there is probably ( almost certainly ) a better way but as no one else had answered I thought I'd have a quick look. I added a tabindex to the li and the class of current so it could gain focus. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y13fprnw/) Away from the computer now to watch a film, Good luck.

```js
var old=$('#thelist').find('li').attr('id','current');
old.removeAttr( "id" );
var html="<li id='current' tabindex='1'>Goodbye</li>";
$('#thelist').append(html);
$('#current').focus();
```

```css
#current{background-color:lime;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="thelist">
    <li id="current"> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li><li> Hello </li>
</ul>
```